# Labels stuck at 0 using nn.CrossEntropyLoss for binary classification in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

Is the way I am calculating the `loss` or `pred_labels` wrong? I am getting really low accuracy values on my `val` and `test` sets. The dataset is somewhat balanced actually and large enough. I am doing binary classification here.

30% of my dataset is class 0 and 70% is class 1 and dataset includes ~2000 2D tensors of different size ranging from 100x512 to 8000x512 with a median size of 1200x512.

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, n_class, batch_size):
        super(Classifier, self).__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.transformer = VisionTransformer()
        #self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduce=False)
        #self.criterion = nn.BCELoss(reduce=False)
        #self.criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(reduce=False) # weighted loss
        #self.criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss() # balanced loss
        #self.criterion = nn.BCELoss()
        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()


    def forward(self, X, labels):

        stacked_X = torch.stack(X)
        out = self.transformer(stacked_X)
        #labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.float32)
        labels = torch.tensor(labels)
        #m = nn.Sigmoid()
 
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            print(out[:,1]-out[:,0])
            #loss = self.criterion(m(out[:,1]-out[:,0]), labels.cuda())
       
            loss = self.criterion(out, labels.cuda())

        #pred_labels = out.data.max(1)[1]
        pred_labels = out.argmax(dim=1)
        labels = labels.int()
        return pred_labels, labels, loss
```

`evaluator.get_scores 0.3194444444444444` (showing ~30 of my data which is label 0)

For calculating accuracy, I am using this code snippet:

```
class ConfusionMatrix(object):

    def __init__(self, n_classes):
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        # axis = 0: prediction
        # axis = 1: target
        self.confusion_matrix = np.zeros((n_classes, n_classes))

    def _fast_hist(self, label_true, label_pred, n_class):
        hist = np.zeros((n_class, n_class))
        hist[label_pred, label_true] += 1

        return hist

    def update(self, label_trues, label_preds):
        for lt, lp in zip(label_trues, label_preds):
            tmp = self._fast_hist(lt.item(), lp.item(), self.n_classes)    #lt.item(), lp.item()
            self.confusion_matrix += tmp

    def get_scores(self):
        """Returns accuracy score evaluation result.
            - overall accuracy
            - mean accuracy
            - mean IU
            - fwavacc
        """
        hist = self.confusion_matrix
        # accuracy is recall/sensitivity for each class, predicted TP / all real positives
        # axis in sum: perform summation along

        if sum(hist.sum(axis=1)) != 0:
            acc = sum(np.diag(hist)) / sum(hist.sum(axis=1))
            print('acc is: ', acc)
        else:
            acc = 0.0

        return acc

    def plotcm(self):
        print(self.confusion_matrix)

    def reset(self):
        self.confusion_matrix = np.zeros((self.n_classes, self.n_classes))
```

and during the test phase, with 1 epoch, I am using this:

```
if epoch % 1 == 0:
        with torch.no_grad():
            model.eval()
            print("evaluating...")

            total = 0.
            batch_idx = 0
            val_preds = []
            val_labels = []
            predictions = []
            actuals = []
            for i_batch, sample_batched in enumerate(dataloader_val):         
                val_pred, val_label, val_loss = evaluator.eval_test(sample_batched, model)
                val_epoch_loss += val_loss
                val_preds.extend(val_pred.tolist())
                val_labels.extend(val_label)
                total += len(val_label)
                evaluator.metrics.update(torch.tensor(val_label).cuda(), val_pred)
            print('evaluator.get_scores', evaluator.get_scores())
```

Here's how out from transformer looks like:

```
transformer out:  tensor([[ 0.4381, -0.6186],
        [ 0.4252, -0.4492],
        [ 1.0657, -0.5201],
        [ 0.8421, -0.6315],
        [ 0.9444, -0.5340],
        [ 0.9247, -0.6726],
        [ 1.1587, -0.9463],
        [ 1.0038, -1.0780],
        [ 1.4244, -1.0721],
        [ 0.4215, -0.7684],
        [ 0.7522, -0.8166],
        [ 1.2995, -0.9579],
        [ 0.8080, -0.6492],
        [ 1.0144, -0.5562],
        [ 1.0666, -1.0291],
        [ 0.3030, -0.7651],
        [ 0.5221, -0.6741],
        [ 1.1583, -0.4493],
        [ 0.6098, -1.0080],
        [ 0.3495, -1.0742],
        [ 0.2278, -0.7298],
        [ 0.5189, -0.6456],
        [ 0.3409, -0.3661],
        [ 0.9637, -0.9262],
        [ 1.0781, -0.9345],
        [ 1.0993, -1.0937],
        [ 0.8297, -0.6071],
        [ 0.5423, -1.1961],
        [ 0.7860, -0.6777],
        [-0.2522, -0.9376],
        [ 0.6013, -0.9057],
        [ 0.9975, -0.1858]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
labels:  tensor([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=torch.int32)
pred labels:  tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], device='cuda:0')
```

I ran the training for 50 epochs and result is same. pred_labels are stuck at 0.

Comment: Have you tried other classical models and the issue is the same?